# MySql - Update with Select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I need to update a table with a select inside. This is my query so far:

```
Update T_STATO_CASA
  Set  UTENTE = 'Admin'
Where ID_CASA in (
                  Select ID 
                    From T_CASA 
                   Where ID_RICHIESTA 
                      In (437869, 437233, 437235, 437876)
                  )
```

But it returns the following error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

> =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

or when the subquery is used as an expression."
The subquery returns exactly 4 results if I run it separately. Is my syntax wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: all the suggested solutions that are using JOIN give me syntax error, as if MySql expects only the update-set-where command sequence. For instance I cannot write something like

```
update T_STATO_CASA as x
set [...]
where [...]
```

because it gives me syntax error: "Incorrect syntax near word AS. Expected SET"

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t_stato_casa x
  JOIN t_casa y
    ON y.id = x.id_casa
   SET x.utente = 'admin'  
 WHERE y.id_richiesta IN(437869, 437233, 437235, 437876)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your subquery will return more than one row of record

The more suitable way is to use `JOIN` instead

```
  UPDATE T_STATO_CASA
    JOIN T_CASA t 
      ON t.id = ID_CASA 
     AND t.ID_RICHIESTA 
      IN (437869, 437233, 437235, 437876)
     SET UTENTE = 'Admin
```

If you still want to use subquery,you need to use `group_concat` to make the result into one record

Comment: The use of a subquery seems redundant - and b <> t

Answer (score 0):

This was the right syntax:

```
UPDATE t_stato_casa
SET
UTENTE = 'Admin'
FROM
    t_stato_casa AS sc
INNER JOIN T_CASA AS c
ON c.ID = sc.ID_CASA
WHERE
    c.ID_RICHIESTA in (437869, 437233, 437235, 437876)
```

Answer (score 0):

using alias, (MySQL)

```
update T_STATO_CASA as x
set x.UTENTE='Admin'
where x.ID_CASA in (
select ID from T_CASA
where ID_RICHIESTA in (437869, 437233, 437235, 437876)
);
```

Referencing of a table is needed to be done correctly.